# Ubuntu 18.04, compress and split large file with 7z, not working

Tags: nautilus, compression, 7zip

I need to compress and split a large (64 GB) file in 4 parts on Ubuntu 18.04.

It needs to be extracted on Windows later and I thought I would try using 7zip.

I tried from the GUI in Nautilus but there's no option to split it, I can only just compress it:

[image]

I do not know if the 7z version I had was the correct one, so I tried re-installing it:

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

but without any difference.

Then, I tried running the command:

```
7z a -v15g output.7z nano_backup_00.img
```

to try and split the file in 15 GB parts.

The process goes on for a while, but it stops too early.

It only produces:

- output.7z.001 -> 16 GB
- output.7z.002 -> 10.5 MB

If I try to extract output.7z.001, I get the error:

```
output.7z.001: empty archive
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` after 7zip reports being finished? Have you tried including the type? `-t7z` to ensure the tool is using the proper encoding? 

Comment: Nothing related to 7zip in the log file you indicated. As for the rest of your suggestions, could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Try installing P7Zip Desktop, see: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-p7zip-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/